# 2nd GPU exclusively for VMs (GTX 1070 with GTX 970)

Tags: virtual-machine, nvidia, qemu, pci, gpu-passthrough

a few weeks ago I upgraded my almost 10 year old PC. I replaced my GTX 970 with a GTX 1070. The thing is, I feel bad when replacing working hardware without real cause. The new GPU actually made things better but the PC worked well before and my old GPU is still in great condition.

Now I got the idea to put my GTX 970 back in as secondary GPU.I would prefer to keep it deactivated and only use it for VMs. Now my question is twofold:

1. I need some education on hardware capabilities. How bad is it, when PCIe 3.0 x16 is throttled down to x8?
2. How can I deactivate my GTX 970 until VM use and will this allow my main GPU to run on full x16 while the secondary GPU is deactivated?

To 1:
MOBO: ASRock Z97 Pro4 with 2 PCIe x16 slots, here is the [Manual](https://download.asrock.com/Manual/Z97%20Pro4.pdf)

CPU: i5-4460 (supports 16 PCI Lanes)

GPU1: GTX 1070

GPU2: GTX 970

If I put the 2nd GPU in, because of the CPU, the connected PCIe Slots will throttled down to x8 if I understand that correctly.
I read that with GEN 3 this is normally not too bad, since the GEN 3 cards from back then didn't really utilize the PCIe 3.0 x16 architecture. So if I understand that correctly the Downgrade to 2 PCIe 3.0 x8 is equivalent to 2 PCIe 2.0 x16. Which should be enough for this GPUs. Can someone explain that a bit for me? Especially in regards to drawbacks. I am not really panning to do any serious gaming on the VMs but I want to use a tool called ProFantasy. You make maps with that and it works like a CAD program. Would you expect serious impact on performance in this regard? Also I want to experiment with GPU pass through on QEMU/KVM machines.

2. If I saw that correctly I can de- and reactivate nVidia GPUs as by this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/654075/how-can-i-disable-and-later-re-enable-one-of-my-nvidia-gpus) with `nvidia-smi`:

Deactivate

```
nvidia-smi -i 0000:xx:00.0 -pm 0
nvidia-smi drain -p 0000:xx:00.0 -m 1
```

and
Reactivate

```
nvidia-smi drain -p 0000:xx:00.0 -m 0
```

When done, will the second GPU be deactivated for real? Meaning there will be no throttling for my first GPU to x8 anymore?

Thank you for your help in advance.